# Using Calendar to reset counted steps every midnight

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am building an android app where it counts user's steps. The purpose is to count steps from midnight of the previous day to midnight of the each day. This is how I set up my Calendar object. It is a Java question really.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
    Log.i(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));
```

And the outpup is

```
Range Start: 2015.05.14 09:25:13
Range End: 2015.05.15 09:25:13
```

So as you can see the output. I count the steps between that period. If I enter the few minutes later,the date format will look like

```
Range Start: 2015.05.14 09:27:07
Range End: 2015.05.15 09:27:07
```

I want it to be like

```
 Range Start: 2015.05.14 00:00:00
 Range End: 2015.05.15 00:00:00
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get today's date:

```
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
```

Set this date to tonight (and store it!):

```
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

When you have midnight, just add +1 to day to get tomorrow's

```
date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I get an exception.Invalid end time: 1431644400000
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source)

Comment: If i change the last line to date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1),I can see the date format I want.

Comment: oh, sorry, you wanted one day ago... My bad!. `-1` is the correct way, yes... but you get the point, that's the important!